# Using jQuery to select a button that was created with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select a button that is made using a jQuery statement. This is the button:

```
$('#mainTable').append('<tr><td>' + 
    elem.date + '</td><td><button class="dButton">Click here</button></td></tr>')
```

Then here's the selector for the button:

```
$(".dButton").click(function () {
  alert("alert");
})
```

I've checked that the top bit of code is called first so the button is created first, and then the second bit, but whenever I click the button it just won't run the second bit of code.

Comment: It is called delegation: `$('#mainTable').on("click",".dButton"),function () {`

Comment: your code is working